# Putting images side by side without gaps between images with subfigure

Tags: floats

I would like to know how we can put images side by side like [here](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) as in Figure 4. The images are attached very closely. From my internet search, I found only solutions that putting images side by side but with some small gaps in betweeen, which what I don't want. Below is the MWE of what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage[style=base]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure*}[tp]
  % \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig1.jpg}\label{fig:fig1}
    \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig2.jpg}\label{fig:fig2}
    \end{subfigure}\\
  \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig3.jpg}\label{fig:fig3}
    \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.1\textwidth}\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig4.jpg}\label{fig:fig4}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you should provide a MWE, that we can show, how to do this. It should be simple `\includegraphics{image-1}\includegraphics{image-2} ...`

Comment: Just don't leave a space. Did you try it? Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @Zarko: I've added the WME accordingly.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks for the idea, I've tried but didn't work.

Comment: A MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What about Zarko's solution is not working? Looks perfectly fine to me. Make sure your pictures do not contain a white border.

Comment: Yes, with Zarko's solution is not working. When I see, the picture it doesn't have a white border. But in any case, is there a way that we can ignore the white border with latex command perhaps?

Comment: @Shah your MWE does not compile, I doubt anyone will be able to help you until it does. Use the `mwe` package and include placeholder images from that package, such as `example-image-a.png`.

Comment: First, a subfigure is basically a minipage, so no [h] option.  Second without a caption, there are no counters for \label to reference.

Comment: @bers You don't need to include the `mwe` package. Just use the images.

Comment: @cfr this assumes that the `mwe` package is already installed. I use MiKTeX with on-the-fly package installation, and I guess without explicitly including the `mwe` package, the document would not compile on a fresh installation.

Comment: @bers OK, but in other cases it won't compile at all if it isn't installed. But people seem to think you need to load the package to use the images, which just isn't true. It is true that you need to install it to use them. And it may be that some configurations are such that trying to load it can trigger the installation, but it is still misleading, I think, to tell users to load it.

Comment: @cfr so how likely is it that you have an `example-image-a` in your graphics search path, but no `mwe` package installed? In other words, how likely is it that the document compiles *without* `\includepackage{mwe}`, but not *with* that command?

Comment: @bers Obviously improbable, but that was not my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution measures the images using `\sbox` and uses that width as the width of the subfigure.  An easier solution would be to not use subfigures.

Note: (almost) every time you end a line with a brace you add a space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=base]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[tp]
  % \centering
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig1.jpg}}%
  \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig2.jpg}}%
  \begin{subfigure}{\wd0}\usebox0\end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{\wd1}\usebox1\end{subfigure}\\
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig3.jpg}}%
  \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{fig4.jpg}}%
  \begin{subfigure}{\wd0}\usebox0\end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{\wd1}\usebox1\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```